# I have different file sizes in VBS dictionary want total size

Tags: vbscript

```
CCDictionary.Add File.Name, File.Size
```

I have dictionary where in I will add some random number of files, with random file sizes, want to determine the total file size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following would accomplish what you are looking for. A For Each loop adding the size together into one value.

```
set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
oDic.add "Report1", 128
oDic.add "Report2", 256
oDic.add "Report3", 512

For Each obj in oDic.keys
    Size = Size + oDic(obj)
Next
Set oDic = Nothing

Msgbox(size)
```

Comment: Thanks @Moir it was a reliable answer for me.

Comment: Excellent, really glad this worked out for you!